# как увеличить точность расчетов позиции объекта в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю ритм игру. Необходимо поворачивать объект по орбите вокруг другого, а так же иногда изменять радиус орбиты. Пробовал делать через Lerp, но то как это выглядит мне не подходит, оно должно перемещаться равномерно, в то время как Lerp делает это резко. По этому я рассчитываю угол на который нужно повернутся, после вычисляю скорость, с которой нужно повернуться в секундах, а затем умножаю на Time.fixedDeltaTime. Таким образом каждый кадр оно рассчитывает это все и поворачивает объект. Это происходит равномерно, НО. Точность перемещения не до 0.0001, как в случае с Lerp, а всего до 0.01 и это очень заметно, если сделать два скрина в одно и то же время но запустив игру дважды, то разница получается очень заметной, а поскольку точка, в которую должен переместится объект, показывается заранее, то это будет заметно и во время игры.
Вот код который я написал НЕ через Lerp:

```
float b = Vector2.Distance(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.position, bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.position);
float b2 = Mathf.Pow(b, 2);
float c = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].X, bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].Y), bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.position);
float c2 = Mathf.Pow(c, 2);
float a2 = Mathf.Pow(Vector2.Distance(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.position, new Vector2(bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].X, bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].Y)), 2);

float alfa = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Acos((b2 + c2 - a2) / (2 * b * c));

float rotation_speed = alfa / (bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].MS - songPosition);

float bLocal = Vector2.Distance(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.position), bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.position));
float cLocal = Vector2.Distance(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(new Vector2(bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].X, bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].Y)), bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.position));

float transform_speed = (cLocal - bLocal) / (bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].MS - songPosition);

bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z + (bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].RotationDirection * rotation_speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.localPosition.x, bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.localPosition.y + (transform_speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
```

А вот через Lerp:

```
float b = Vector2.Distance(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.position, bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.position);
float b2 = Mathf.Pow(b, 2);
float c = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].X, bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].Y), bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.position);
float c2 = Mathf.Pow(c, 2);
float a2 = Mathf.Pow(Vector2.Distance(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.position, new Vector2(bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].X, bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].Y)), 2);

float alfa = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Acos((b2 + c2 - a2) / (2 * b * c));
                
float cLocal = Vector2.Distance(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(new Vector2(bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].X, bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].Y)), bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.position));

float t = Mathf.InverseLerp(bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i]].MS, bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].MS, songPosition);

bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z + (bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].RotationDirection * alfa)), t);
bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.localPosition = Vector2.Lerp(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.localPosition, new Vector2(0, cLocal), t);
```

Как можно увеличить точность не прибегая к функции Lerp?
Так же пробовал изменять Time.fixedDeltaTime, но на точность это не влияло.

Добавлено:
Я понял в чем была ошибка и почему Lerp делал это не плавно, я каждый раз передавал текущее положение, а не заранее записанное. Я это исправил, и теперь записываю положение, но вопрос остался, как увеличить точность, ибо теперь, уже с функцией Lerp появилась проблема низкой точности.
Вот код:

```
float b = Vector2.Distance(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.position, bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.position);
float b2 = Mathf.Pow(b, 2);
float c = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].X, bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].Y), bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.position);
float c2 = Mathf.Pow(c, 2);
float a2 = Mathf.Pow(Vector2.Distance(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.position, new Vector2(bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].X, bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].Y)), 2);

float alfa = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Acos((b2 + c2 - a2) / (2 * b * c));
             
float cLocal = Vector2.Distance(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(new Vector2(bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].X, bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].Y)), bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.position));                

float t = Mathf.InverseLerp(bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i]].MS, bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].MS, songPosition);

bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(rotation[i], Quaternion.Euler(bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z + (bitmap.GamePoints[i].Positions[PointsPos[i] + 1].RotationDirection * alfa)), t);                 
bitmap.GamePoints[i].PointObject.transform.localPosition = Vector2.Lerp(position[i], new Vector2(0, cLocal), t);
```

параметры rotation[i] и position[i] меняются каждый раз по достижении определенного момента в песне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, проблема была в параметре t - показатель времени аудиосистемы, как оказалось, обновляется 50 раз в секунду, и в расчеты параметра t просто не попадали нужные значения. Решение может и не самое правильное, но я просто приравниваю t к одному когда t принимает значения больше 0.96